# Data race occurs with xml.Marshal

Tags: go

I'm getting a strange data race reported when I use `xml.Marshal` on a struct. I am 99% sure that I am not sending the same variable or something like that - instead I get intermittent errors in which the marshal function believes that it is causing a data race.

Here's the code (simplified a bit but all functional elements are there):

```
// this is run prior to any calls being sent to the below functions
func Setup() (descriptor *serviceDescriptor) {
    descriptor = new(serviceDescriptor)

    wpChan := make(chan *Call)
    for i := 1; i < 100; i++ {
        go serviceWorker(wpChan)
    }
    descriptor.wpChan = wpChan

    return
}   

// called externally to initiate a call
func (s *serviceDescriptor) Add(c *Call) {
    go s.makeCall(c)
}

// sends a call to the worker pool set up in the Setup() function
func (s *serviceDescriptor) makeCall(c *Call) {

    cw := new(callwrapper)
    cw.internal = new(etFullCall)
    cw.internal.Calldata = c

    /// this is a channel that the next function listens to
    s.wpChan <- ct

   // the result is sent back on a channel and processed here
}

// this is a function 
func worker(wpChan chan *callwrapper) {
    for cw := range wpChan {
        v := new(Result)

        // this is where the data race occurs.    
        byt, err := xml.Marshal(cw.internal)

        // do stuff with the result down here

    }

}
```

Here's the error:

```
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write by goroutine 115:
  runtime.copy()
      /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/slice.c:120 +0x0
  encoding/xml.(*parentStack).push()
      /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/encoding/xml/marshal.go:901 +0x2bd
  encoding/xml.(*printer).marshalStruct()
      /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/encoding/xml/marshal.go:819 +0x58c
  encoding/xml.(*printer).marshalValue()
      /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/encoding/xml/marshal.go:524 +0x12a8
  encoding/xml.(*Encoder).Encode()
      /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/encoding/xml/marshal.go:153 +0x83
  encoding/xml.Marshal()
      /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/encoding/xml/marshal.go:72 +0x9d
  exacttarget.serviceWorker()
      /service.go:94 +0x20e

Previous write by goroutine 114:
  runtime.copy()
      /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/slice.c:120 +0x0
  encoding/xml.(*parentStack).push()
      /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/encoding/xml/marshal.go:901 +0x2bd
  encoding/xml.(*printer).marshalStruct()
      /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/encoding/xml/marshal.go:819 +0x58c
  encoding/xml.(*printer).marshalValue()
      /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/encoding/xml/marshal.go:524 +0x12a8
  encoding/xml.(*Encoder).Encode()
      /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/encoding/xml/marshal.go:153 +0x83
  encoding/xml.Marshal()
      /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/encoding/xml/marshal.go:72 +0x9d
  exacttarget.serviceWorker()
     /service.go:94 +0x20e

Goroutine 115 (running) created at:
  service.Setup()
     /service.go:39 +0x112
  /src.processSingleUser()
      /main_test.go:405 +0xdf
  /src.testAddLists()
      /main_test.go:306 +0x1f2

Goroutine 114 (running) created at:
  service.Setup()
     /service.go:39 +0x112
  /src.processSingleUser()
      /main_test.go:405 +0xdf
  src.testAddLists()
      /main_test.go:306 +0x1f2
```

Comment: Let's play spot the php programmer! something in the omitted code gotta be the reason for the race.

Comment: @OneOfOne that is possible, certainly. We have made an effort to make sure each operation is idempotent. Every goroutine is creating a new call struct and no further manipulation is done to them.  Please let me know if there is more information you would need in order to help debug this.

Comment: reading that stack trace and the code behind it I'm 90% sure it's a false positive. And if it was a true positive you wouldn't be able to fix it without changing `slice.c` or reimplementing the xml encoder.

Comment: can you try to reproduce a small test case?

Comment: @tomwilde the go race detector is incapable of producing false positives, so you can be exactly 0% sure it's one.

Comment: As for the actual race, it doesn't look like one from `encoding/xml`. The more likely thing is that you're passing a single pointer to multiple `xml.Marshal`'s. There is little to help without the full code.

Comment: @Wessie I will check my pointers, thanks.

Comment: @Wessie; it's formally false-negative free; not false-positive free. Although you're probably right that something as important as the stdlib has been checked thoroughly.

Comment: `Setup()` is broken: It won't set up the passed in serviceDescriptor, it just does some stuff on local variables and returns without side effects. Ah, and the race detector is pretty good, false positives are very unlikely.

Comment: Not to make this comment thread any longer but I take back my previous comment; @Wessie is right in what he said.